# How to solve Absolute Value Equations Algebraically

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this math problem that I'm not sure how to solve because it's different from the rest of the problems provided by my book. Find the horizontal (x-intercept) and vertical (y-intercepts) intercepts of $f(x)=3|x-2|-4.$ In particular, how do I find the intercepts in regards to the absolute value portion of the equation?

Comment: What do you mean by "solving" a function?  Do you mean graphing it?  But in that case, simply break into two intervals (in which $x-2$ is $≥0$ or $<0$).  Your function has no vertical asymptotes (clearly).  Horizontal?  Well, what happens if $x$ is a large positive number?  What if it is large and negative?

Comment: Vertical intercepts occur when $x=0$. Plugging that in should be simple enough. Horizontal intercepts occur when $3|x-2|=4$ and you just need to take $(x-2)$ and $(2-x)$ to get your solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The x-intercept is located at $(0,f(0))$, where $f(0)=3|(0-2)-4|$.
The y-intercepts are located at $(f^{-1}(0), 0)$, where $x=f^{-1}(0)$, that is all values of $x$ such that $0=3|x-2|-4$.

When solving absolute value problems, isolate the absolute value term, then set the absolute value term equal to plus or minus the opposite side:
$4/3=|x-2| \implies x-2= 4/3 $ or $x-2 = -4/3$.